# Can I use a linux-based ORM from multiple languages?

Tags: python, ruby, database, oop, orm

The predominant ORMs that run in a linux-based environment seem to be written around a specific language.

Microsoft LINQ, however, supports access from a number of languages.  Can I do this in linux-land (i.e. non-LINQ-land, non-JVM-land), for example between native versions of Python and Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only way to do this is to use languages which share a common VM, such as .NET CLR (and LINQ) or the Java JVM (Hibernate, Eclipse Link, etc).

So for the various languages running in their native implementation, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't really make sense. Presumably LINQ, like any .NET library, can be used in any language that runs in the CLR: C#, VB, IronPython, IronRuby, etc.

The most common cross-language runtime that works on Linux is the Java VM, and you can use Java libraries - including ORMs like JDO - in any language that uses that VM: Java, Scala, Clojure, Jython, JRuby, etc.

Comment: Thanks! By "in linux" I mean  to imply "in linux and without using LINQ".  I'm not aware of anything that will allow Ruby or Python to use Java libraries like this.

Comment: But that's exactly my point. Any Java library will work with any JVM-based language, *including* the JVM versions of Python and Ruby, which are Jython and JRuby.

Comment: I'll update the question to note that "linux-based" is implying "native linux implementations of languages."  Emphasis on an inter-language ORM, rather than on getting multiple languages running on the same VM. Thanks!

Comment: Then your comparison is even less relevant, because (as I note in the answer) the reason why LINQ works on multiple languages is because those languages all use the same VM, ie the .NET CLR (common language runtime).

Comment: lol, then I guess that just boils down to an answer of "no" for the question!